# Typescript: Generate object with mapped properties from enumeration values

Tags: typescript

I'm looking for a way to generate an object with values computed during compilation from enumeration values and pre-defined function calls - basically the idea is to bind some arguments of a function with keys. For example, assume I have the following:

```js
enum LogLevel {
  error = 'error',
  warning = 'warning'
  info = 'info'
}

const log = (level: LogLevel, message: string) => {
  console.log(`Level: ${level}, Message: ${message}`);
}
```

I'm looking for syntax like:

```js
const logger = {
  [level in LogLevel]: (msg: string) => log(level, msg)
}
```

which does not work (compilation fails with `A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.`)

I'd like that to be functionally equal to:

```js
const logger = {
  [LogLevel.error]: (msg: string) => log(LogLevel.error, msg),
  [LogLevel.warning]: (msg: string) => log(LogLevel.warning, msg),
  [LogLevel.info]: (msg: string) => log(LogLevel.info, msg)
}
```

so that I can use it like that:

```js
logger.error("Bad things happened")
logger.warn("Help me")
```

The real use case contains many elements in the enumeration and I'd rather not modify the object each time when adding new ones. I know I can at least add a type constraint that would require all keys from enumeration to be present in the type with a very similar syntax:

```js
type Logger = {
  [level in LogLevel]: (msg: string) => void
}
```

but since the values are repetitive and really just boilerplate, I'd like them to be generated automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only thing to keep in mind here is that `TypeScript` types are stripped away after compilation to JavaScript, so you need to generate your `Logger` dynamically.

```js
const allLogLevels = ['error', 'warning', 'info'] as const;
type LogLevel = typeof allLogLevels[number]; // 'error' | 'warning' | 'info'

type Logger = {
  [level in LogLevel]: (msg: string) => void
}

const log = (level: LogLevel, message: string) => {
  console.log(`Level: ${level}, Message: ${message}`);
}

function createLogger() {
  const logger: Partial<Logger> = {};

  for (let key of allLogLevels) {
    logger[key] = (message: string) => log(key, message);
  }

  return logger as Logger;
}

// runtime
const logger = createLogger();

logger.error('test error.');
logger.warning('test warning.');
logger.info('test info.');
```

TypeScript Playground example is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=28&ssc=27&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgGwQGRAc2QUwG6YRGAXhgG0ByTAJ0pErIBoYyB3OSsASzDQaa4DMQZALrwCoSFADcAKBlQAngAdMMVBhx4iMRSpD94SdVlz4SYAK4BbAEZVhs%20ctXq0VbQG8ZMUgk0IYLjV0EzxhAC4YAAorCDRI6EouNABKIgA%20GGwQDgATGQBfOQloGAR0bSi-U0jjf0YrTAgIODcEqCTuNMJMrx8SkD8AOnK0KIADUIRIgBIParwCxgBZJpa2mDnG5tbMAvGU2SKZfgswYCgOcBhgSkw4KExXKii0vpvwUtG3SkiABTYl0QAB5npRMsQPAVHD5BJRon5YABrTAKGD6QwoEL%20CBvbw%20MroH4kFEKUTEGJrXbtTqpDKEsakhpUtyHfHHHx3KAWdgMn5iYJoH5HOQAelFMEoZ0ujRkJVg33cxFu90eYNejkVlCGVBolCiZEepV1tCGZDZWqGrHYyQNRtg1s43DNFqJVCGAhAdqasE9LqkQA).